# Are other aliens aware of the mirror universe?

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe

Whenever we go into the mirror universe, it always involves Starfleet is some way, but are other aliens, for example, Vulcans or Klingons aware of the mirror universe?

To clarify, I don't mean someone telling you, for example, Sisko has gone into the mirror universe many times, and he would have undoubtedly told Kira (Bajoran) or Dax (Trill), even if it was off screen, about his adventures.

I was wondering if Vulcans, Klingon or other aliens are aware of the mirror universe, and attempted to enter it.

Comment: What do you mean by "other aliens"? Who are the "not-other" aliens?

Comment: What I meant was, whenever they go into the mirror universe, it's always Starfleet. In other words, any non Starfleet vessels or personnel

Comment: I think it's safe to say that Q is aware of the mirror universe. I wouldn't put it past the other Star Trek heavyweights, either (Nagilum, Edo god, etc.), but there's no way to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the Ferengi.  After Bashir and Kira crossed over it seems more folks know about it.  "The Emperor's New Cloak" Star Trek: Deep Space Nine season 7 episode 12.  Grand Nagus Zek was in the mirror universe trying to set up trading and got kidnapped.  There is a bit of continuity error involving cloaking devices but I suppose it could be retconned by unreliable narrators or infinite parallel universes.

Comment: I remember that episode, if only Rom or Quark could have brought that Ezri back to the prime universe!